# jQuery script keeps repeating

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following script which `fadeIn` a div when the user scrolls 200px from the top and animates some custom circles. This works (not in the best way i guess, I've thrown some scripts to getter to make it work).

My script:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 200){ // 235  
        $('.hideme').fadeIn(2000);
    }
    $('.first.circle').circleProgress({
        value: 1,
        startAngle: -Math.PI / 1 * 1,
        fill: {gradient: [['#ff6600', .3], ['#f2833a', .7]], gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4}
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
        $(this).find('strong').html(Math.abs(36 * progress).toFixed(0) + '');
    });

    $('.second.circle').circleProgress({
        fill: {gradient: ['#0681c4', '#0681c4']},
        startAngle: -Math.PI / 1 * 2,
        value: 1
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
        $(this).find('strong').html(Math.round(160 * progress) + '');
    });

    $('.third.circle').circleProgress({
        startAngle: -Math.PI / 3 * 3,
        value: 1,
        fill: {gradient: [['#09c109', .9], ['#298e29', .1]], gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4}
    }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
        $(this).find('strong').html(Math.abs(9.4 * progress).toFixed(1) + '');
    });
})
```

The problem is that the script keeps repeating it self, if I just scroll up or down a little bit? I can't seem to find out whats doing this? How do I stop this from happening...

I've looked trough Stackoverflow and the answers given there don't seem to work.
If anyone has an other script that does the samething?

All I want to do is have the div `.hideme` fadeIn when it comes in the viewport of the page and then start the circle animation... thanks in advance!

Comment: every time you scroll even a little bit, there are multiple scroll events firing - you need to re-think your logic

Comment: It keeps repeating itsself because once you exceeded the threshold of 200px from the top of your page your if is always true,

Comment: Yeah, thats what I thought :)

Comment: Be careful, you're assigning `on('circle-animation-progress'` every time you scroll. That will make thousands of event handlers for your `circle`s.

Comment: What if I do something like `if .hideme has opacity 1` then run the circle code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var lastPosition = 0;
$(window).on('scroll', function () {
    let scrollTop = $(this).scrollTop();
    let $hideMe = $('.hideme');
    let $firstCircle = $('.first.circle');
    let $secondCircle = $('.second.circle');
    let $thirdCircle = $('.third.circle');
    if (lastPosition <= 200 && scrollTop > 200){ // 235  
        // if the last scroll position is under 201 and
        // the actual position is above 200, start the animations

        $hideMe.fadeIn(2000);

        $firstCircle.circleProgress({
            value: 1,
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 1 * 1,
            fill: {gradient: [['#ff6600', .3], ['#f2833a', .7]], gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4}
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
            $(this).find('strong').html(Math.abs(36 * progress).toFixed(0) + '');
        });

        $secondCircle.circleProgress({
            fill: {gradient: ['#0681c4', '#0681c4']},
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 1 * 2,
            value: 1
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress) {
            $(this).find('strong').html(Math.round(160 * progress) + '');
        });

        $thirdCircle.circleProgress({
            startAngle: -Math.PI / 3 * 3,
            value: 1,
            fill: {gradient: [['#09c109', .9], ['#298e29', .1]], gradientAngle: Math.PI / 4}
        }).on('circle-animation-progress', function(event, progress, stepValue) {
            $(this).find('strong').html(Math.abs(9.4 * progress).toFixed(1) + '');
        });
    } else if (scrollTop <= 200) {
        // if the current position is under 201, cancel the animations

        $hideMe.fadeOut(200);

        // ....
        // cancel all the circles, you'll have to check the correct methods needed
        // ....
    }

    lastPosition = scrollTop;
});
```

Comment: Great stuff. This works. I can tweek it some if needed. thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

You can write your Jquery like this `$(window).one("scroll",function(){`, this will bind it only one time.

Comment: That has nothing to do with his problem.

Comment: @silentw : If I understand correctly, his method getting called whenever user scrolls through the page, as he asked he wants it to execute the animation thing only once.

Comment: Ok, but that would only work on the first mouse scroll, even if it wasn't `scrollTop() > 200` and then would "shutdown".